# Windows phone live tile

Tags: windows-phone, live-tile

[image: Tile]

I want make live tile like picture.How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good starting guide is available [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Working_with_Live_Tiles_in_Windows_Phone_7). What you should consider is the fact that the images you see in the Live Tile background are dynamically generated (e.g. on the server) and then returned to the phone through a pre-defined channel.

Answer (score 4):

The tiles created above were more then likely created server side.  That being said a lot has changed between windows phone 7.1 and windows phone 8.  Here is [a link](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Live_Tile_Templates_in_Windows_Phone_8) to the  updated information on windows phone 8 live tiles.

Answer (score 2):

On previous versions of Windows and Windows Phone, working with Live Tiles were restricted to some predefined templates.

When you see more complex tile, you can bet that the developer generated the image programmatically and then applied it on tile background.

With Windows 10, the Adaptive Tile brings a lot of new possibilities.

```
...
<binding template="TileLarge" hint-textStacking="center">
  <group>
    <subgroup hint-weight="1"/>
    <subgroup hint-weight="2">
      <image src="Assets/Apps/Hipstame/hipster.jpg" hint-crop="circle"/>
    </subgroup>
    <subgroup hint-weight="1"/>
  </group>

  <text hint-style="title" hint-align="center">Hi,</text>
  <text hint-style="subtitleSubtle" hint-align="center">MasterHip</text>
</binding>
...
```

You can find the full example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiles_and_toasts/archive/2015/06/30/adaptive-tile-templates-schema-and-documentation.aspx)

For previous versions, you can find examples at http://talkitbr.com/2015/05/25/live-tiles/